# jsDoc - set type without importing file

Tags: javascript, class, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

I'm using Angular 1 in VScode. I have a main file that defines all my services, controllers etc and `require`'s them against Angular.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .service('myService', require('./myService.js')
    .controller('myController', require('./myController.js');
```

and the service:

```
class MyService {
    constructor() {}
}

module.exports = MyService;
```

and my controller

```
class MyController {
    constructor(myService) {    
        /** @type {MyService} */
        this.myService = myService;
    }
}

module.exports = MyController;
```

As a result intellisense has no idea what `myService` is within the controller. I had hoped that the jsDoc comment would have solved this issue as both files are within the same work-space but it does not.

I have seen the `type-def` comment and tried writing a custom type in the service file :`/** {MyService} CustomService */` then reference the CustomService type in my controller but that doesn't work either.

**In Short**
Is it possible, using jsDoc in VSCode to reference a class from a different file without `requiring` it into the current working file.

Thanks for any insight all.

Answer (score 1):

No, as of VScode 1.14 this is not possible but we are tracking a discussion of this functionality here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14377

Comment: That's brilliant, tried looking through the issues but must have missed this.

Comment: This JSDoc syntax currently works in VSCode `@type {import("./myService.js")}`