# How to reference an exported object in JSDoc without importing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I am trying to reference an object I export, currently I achieved this successfully by importing it and prefixing with "_" so that it does not show up as unused, is there another way to do this?

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
import type { BusinessTime as _BusinessTime } from "@/lib/types/business-time"

/**
 * @returns Open hours for business, see: {@link _BusinessTime BusinessTime}
 */
export function getBusinessTimes() {}
```

Comment: See: [jsDoc - set type without importing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749703/jsdoc-set-type-without-importing-file), or better: [How to make jsDoc “import” work with vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60523475/how-to-make-jsdoc-import-work-with-vscode)

Comment: Apparently TS 2.9 support this already: [Refer to type in different file in JSDoc without importing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255744/1762224)

Comment: So I tried to add a `/** @typedef {import("@/lib/types/business-time").BusinessTime} BusinessTime */` at the top of my file but `@returns Open hours for business, see: {@link BusinessTime}` inside my function's JSDoc, does not link to the actual symbol